# Outer join not showing extra entries

Tags: sql, database, join, outer-join

I have made a query in which 3 tables are used. The first table has all the desired names which I need. The 2nd and 3rd table give me those names on which there is some bill amount. But I need all the names from the 1st table as well.

```
SELECT   a.name,
         nvl(c.bill_amount,0)
    FROM  table_1 a left outer join table_2 b
    ON  a.name = b.name
    left outer join table_3 c on B.phone_number = C.phone_number
         AND B.email = C.email
         where  b.status = 'YES'
         and a.VALID = 'Y';
```

Now, the tables b and c give me limited number of names, lets say 5 on which bill is there. But in table_1, there are 10 names. I want to display them also with 0 bill_amount on their name. I'm using Oracle.

Comment: change the where to this; 'WHERE (b.status = 'YES' OR b.status IS NULL)' or put that into the join (take out of the where clause) 'AND b.status = 'YES''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a `where` clause on the right hand tale basiically makes it an inner join. To keep it `OUTER`, put the condition in the join conditions

Try:

```
SELECT   a.name,
         nvl(c.bill_amount,0)
FROM  table_1 a 
left outer join table_2 b
  ON  a.name = b.name
  and b.status = 'YES'  -- Put it here
left outer join table_3 c 
  on B.phone_number = C.phone_number
  AND B.email = C.email
where a.VALID = 'Y';    -- Only items from the left hand table should go in the where clause
```

Comment: it solved most of the problem, but now I am getting redundant data.

Comment: @Akshay Redundant data? If you are getting duplicates, use `DISTINCT`

Comment: can you help me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541100/fetch-table-name-from-a-column-for-from-clause

Comment: I'm having this problem, b.status = 'YES' condition is not taken into perspective. When I take its value out, status is NULL. But I want only those results in which status = 'YES'

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is right , I would just want to be more precise. The fact is when a left join does not match, the column of the right hand table are set to `NULL`.

Actually NULL is always propagating value in SQL, so `b.status = 'YES'` have the value `NULL` if the join does not math, and then the predicate does not match neither.

The general way to handle this would be `(b.status = 'YES' or b.name IS NULL)` : because `b.name` is the join column it is null if and only if join does not match, which may not be the case for `b.status`.

Because `NULL` is propagating you cannot use `field = NULL` but `field IS NULL` instead.

But it is okay to have it in the join clause when it is more clear.

Comment: I'm having the same problem which you pointed out, b.status = 'YES' condition is not taken into perspective. When I take its value out, status is NULL. But I want only those results in which status = 'YES'