# fetch table name from a column for from clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have a view t with me which has a column for table name and another column which has where clause condition.

```
    id| name|table_in| where_clause

    1 | Sam | t1 | age = 22

    2 | John| t2 | age = 23 and sex = 'male'
```

and so on...

Now, I have put the records in a cursor and I want to run each query.

```
    create or replace procedure create_cursor 
    is

    CURSOR v_records is
    select * from t ;

    begin

    FOR temp IN v_records LOOP
        INSERT INTO myTable (id, name)
        select temp.id, temp.name 
        from temp.table where temp.where_clause;

        END LOOP;


    end;
    /
```

myTable is another table in which I want to put the records for next purpose.

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. There are two possible interpretations of this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Akshay,

Please find the code below for your reference.

```
Create or replace procedure create_cursor is
l_statement varchar2(32767);
cursor v_records is
  select * from t;
begin
for temp in v_records
loop
  l_statement := 'INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) select '||temp.id||','
   ||temp.name|| ' from ' || temp.table1 
   || ' where ' || temp.where_clause;

  execute immediate l_statement;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: He has made a syntax mistake. Please check the comment given by akshay. He said there is an error "Missing Values". Hence i have edited. Please check before posting comment and down vote.

Comment: I already made this change in my sql that's why I didn't mention it. The problem is that the procedure is not executing.

Comment: @APC i hope you know how to run and compile plsql. Before posting that the code doesnt work please check and run the code with valid data. Please learn how to set data for running the plsql code. If you dont then it is not easy to run the code. Also editing others post based on mine is not ethical. learn to understand plsql and then post comments. Cheers. Please find the screenshot below.

Comment: @APC and cant understand from where you got ORA-00904. Seriously. This has made my day. I have used the column names dynamically. Guess what its your data problem. Since you have set your data wrongly you have got that oracle error message. You couldnt understand the error message so "Lets down vote" was your ideology.Way To Go!!!!

Comment: @APC i have just proved that the code is working. Better learn to set the data and try the code before posting or down voting others. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like @akshay has said that he has changed the id and name as dynamic variables just like mine. Again read the earlier comments before posting SO. Cheers!! And yes why not test your PLSQL skills? First accept the mistake you have commit and move on!!

Comment: He also said that the procedure "is not executing". I think the problem is that the OP hasn't given us the structure of T1 and T2. If T1 has a column called SAM then your code would work with the test data the OP posted. So I'm giving up on this thread. I have edited your question so I can withdraw the downvote.

Comment: @APC :/ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You need dynamic sql to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_cursor
IS
  l_statement VARCHAR2(32767);
  CURSOR v_records
  IS
    SELECT * FROM t;
BEGIN
  FOR temp IN v_records
  LOOP
    l_statement := 'INSERT INTO myTable (id, name)
          select id, name from ' || temp.table || 
          ' where ' || temp.where_clause;
    EXECUTE immediate l_statement;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: it is giving me an error in the execute line and saying 'Missing VALUES KEYWORD'

Comment: Output the statement before it is executed and see what it looks like.
Maybe I made a syntax error somewhere. Althought it looks ok to me.

Comment: `name` will be something like 'Sam' or 'John' so it will need quotes. However I would expect to see `ORA-00904: "Sam": invalid identifier'. This is probably trivial to fix once you post the generated INSERT statement that is failing.

Comment: Fixed the code. In the dynamic `insert` NAME and ID are columns belonging to the selected table (T1, T2) so they shouldn't be aliased with the cursor name

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - I think this comment actually refers to the other posted "solution"

Comment: `table` is a reserved keyword

Comment: @APC name and id are taken from the view t itself. So, I think temp.id and temp.name should be there.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this as the answer. The details of tables t1 and t2 are not given in the question so we don't know what columns to select.

Comment: @akshay - so if `T1` has ten records where `age=22` you want ten instances of `(1, 'Sam')` inserted into `mytable`? Not the values for `id` and `name` from `t1`?